# Vector line layer classification with two functions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, line, classification, function

I have a linear geometry layer with the attribute: `"uuid_przys"`. I would like to classify my layer with the uuid-attribute, but only for the objects in the current map view or for the objects that I select.

After classification I would like to have only 5 objects in the layer tree, that are actually visibled on the map:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use data driven override for `Enable symbol layer` to show only symbols for features that A) are selected and B) fulfill a certain condition (here: attribute `value` < 10) using this expression : `is_selected( ) and  "value" <10`.

*Screenshot: for demonstration purpose, I added the original layer showin all features in white or yellow (the selected ones) circles; the duplicated copy of this layer contains the same features, bot only those which are selected and have a `"value"` smaller than 10 are symbolized with a small square and labeled with their `"value"`:*

[image]

*If no points are selected, no features are symbolized. If you make a selection, only those of the selected features that fulifill the condition `"value"<10` are shown:*
[image]

Comment: This is a very helpful option, thank's a lot. but I don't think it will help me

Comment: Sorry, than I think your question is not clear enough. You just say that you want to make a classification, but don't provide further details. Like this, it's impossible to guess how the result should look like and based on what exactly you want to achieve that. Please revise the question.